# Implementation of foldLeft in Scala

Tags: scala, collections, fold

[TraversableOnce](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.11.1/src/library/scala/collection/TraversableOnce.scala) implements `foldLeft` with mutable `var result`.

```
def foldLeft[B](z: B)(op: (B, A) => B): B = {
   var result = z
   this foreach (x => result = op(result, x))
   result
}
```

I understand that it is not practical to implement `foldLeft` recursively. Now I wonder if it is possible to implement `foldLeft` without mutable variables efficiently.

Can it be done ? Why if it cannot ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Tail-recursion is your friend:

```
def foldLeft[A, B](xs: Seq[A], z: B)(op: (B, A) => B): B = {
  def f(xs: Seq[A], acc: B): B = xs match {
    case Seq()   => acc
    case x +: xs => f(xs, op(acc, x))
  }
  f(xs, z)
}
```

Btw, `TraversableOnce` doesn't implement `head` or `tail`, the only way to access the elements is to use `foreach`.

Answer (score 1):

```
object FoldImplement:
  def myFoldLeft(lst: List[Int])(acc: Int)(f: (Int, Int)=>Int): Int =
    lst match
      case List() => acc
      case hd::tl => myFoldLeft(tl)(f(hd,acc))(f)

  @main def runFoldImpl =
    println(myFoldLeft(List(1,3,5))(0)((acc,elem)=>acc+elem))
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
def foldLeft[B](z: B)(op: (B, A) => B): B = {
  val thislist = this.toList
  @tailrec
  def myFold(result: B, list: List[A]): B = list match {
    case Nil => result
    case head :: tail => myFold(op(result,head), tail)
  }
  myFold(z, thislist)
}
```

Comment: Unless the collection is a `List`, the `toList` operation takes `O(n)`. Hence this is an inefficient solution.

Comment: So foldLeft will still be O(n) :p
Like sschaef said, inside `TraversableOnce` the only way to access the elements is `foreach`, so when you really want to do it recursively, you'll have to lose _some_ efficiency...

Comment: So the full answer to this question is: it is possible to implement `foldLeft` without mutable variables in the most efficient way, but not in `TraversableOnce`,  because of the lack of `O(1)` head and tail functions.

Comment: You should probably add this to your answer.

Comment: Shouldn't the overhead be lower when using `toIterator`?